# How could I understand that user pressed X button on cmd window?

Tags: c++, windows, button, cmd, exit

I have written a program in **C++** and before exit I store some data in files. However, if the user clicks on the close box (X) on top right corner I lose those data. Is there a way to detect if the user clicks on the close box, so that I call some functions before exit?

[image: image of cmd]

Comment: Is this on Windows?  If so, take a look at [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) to installer a handler that looks for the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` event:

> A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console (either by clicking Close on the console window's window menu, or by clicking the End Task button command from Task Manager).